# Can we still use eclipse to connect to salesforce and fetch all metadata

Tags: apex, metadata-api, eclipse

Can anyone please share the way we can connect salesforce to eclipse to fetch all meta data. I used to have that earlier couple of years back but unfortuantely it's no longer working.

Force.com plugin site says repository don't exist.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

The Eclipse-based Force.com IDE has been end-of-lifed for a long time. Instead, use Visual Studio Code with the [Salesforce Extension Pack](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/getting-started/install).

The [Org Browser](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/user-guide/org-browser) feature may help to cover what you're looking for from Eclipse, although be aware that VSC works rather differently than Eclipse did.

Comment: Yep, anything involving Eclipse at this point would be painfully manual/home-grown. As a side note, is it too soon for people to start swapping "force.com ide" war stories?

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering working with eclipse was far better then working in vs code. Like code search facility was very fast when we need to search metadata.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @David Reed, VS code is the best and the SF recommended option. And support for force.com IDE of eclipse by Salesforce is no longer available, as stated [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/ide_getting_started.htm)

But assuming extracting of metadata is the main and only aim then below approach can be used.

1. Generate package.xml from [here] (https://packagebuilder.herokuapp.com/) (or any of the similar site or Vs code extensions).
2. Use either [workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php) or [SFDX](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ws_retrieve_pack_xml.htm).

Other useful links could be
[this](https://youtu.be/CUvIuY6l8gM) or [this](https://youtu.be/GBNmNbq02WI)

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate your comments.